# How do you setup types with Bun?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, bun

Bun is currently working on my local machine, but I cannot get it to show all of the typings in my IDE.  How do I set this up to work in VS Code and other editors?

Comment: @KevinB We've answered this question 5+ times in the discord in the past 2 days despite it being in the README. Hopefully people will search here instead of someone needing to take the effort to answer again,

Comment: Sound's like a better fit would be to have a FAQ in your discord for you to link people to.

Comment: @KevinB I will ask if we could do that.  Although, I believe https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244561/10873797 would be sufficient precedent to keep this open?

Comment: fwiw StackOverflow has a mechanism to make it as a "community" wiki. Just mark your answer as a "Community Wiki" one (a little checkbox at bottom left)

Answer (score 20):

Install the [`bun-types` NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bun-types):

```bash
bun add -D @types/bun
```

Or

```bash
npm install -D @types/bun
```

You may need to reload your editor for these types to start showing.

From [the documentation's TypeScript guide](https://bun.sh/docs/installation#typescript)

Comment: This can be done, but has absolutely no effect for me. Neither do I get hints in VS Code, nor does bun script.ts error if I make mistakes

Comment: @NoBullsh1t Please try joining the Bun discord and hopefully we can better help you there.

Comment: After spending hours trying to figure out how to add Bun types to WebStorm... "reload your editor" was what I was missing! 

Comment: I would have expected this to be in the installation or quickstart on https://bun.sh/docs

Comment: Thanks @LiveSource , it is actually on the installation guide and I have updated the information in this answer to follow it along with the link to the section.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this concise information and the link. Worked for me. Had to reload VSCode window. This bunjs stuff is quite amazing.

Comment: This should come pre-configured with Bun, like everything else.

Answer (score 2):

nothing above works for me, i get `Cannot find name 'Bun' .ts(2304)` error [vscode doesnt see bun types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa81g.png)

i restarted vscode, downloaded bun vscode extension, nothing.. still no types are shown.

i used default `bun init` config

UPD
solved by changing to this tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // add Bun type definitions
    "types": ["bun-types"],

    // enable latest features
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",

    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",

    "jsx": "react-jsx", // support JSX
    "allowJs": true, // allow importing `.js` from `.ts`
    "esModuleInterop": true, // allow default imports for CommonJS modules

    // best practices
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```